# Trap not trapping SIGTSTP

Tags: shell-script, signals

I have a script that keeps displaying the login prompt:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
trap '' 2 20
while true; do
    login
done
```

This is part of a bigger project so please don't tell me to just use the system login prompt. It needs to be done through a shell script.

The reason it is in a loop is so that when the user logs out, the script drops them back at the login prompt.

The only issue is that it's possible to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> and kill the script and therefor the prompt. The trap stops <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, but for some reason <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> can still be used to stop the script. I know that it's something to do with the login command because if I replace login with another command like `echo hello` then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> doesn't stop the script anymore (IE it keeps printing hello).

How can I trap <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>?

Comment: What are you using to run this script? For example, I know `systemd` is able to rerun services if they did not exit correctly.

Comment: It's run from /etc/init.d/rc.local when the system starts up.

Comment: I am not actually sure that you can accomplish this with `rc.local`. SysV is rather antiquated, and this is one of many things that newer init daemons have improved upon.

Comment: I don't want to relaunch the service. I just want to stop SIGTSTP from doing anything. My code stops SIGINT so why can't it stop SIGTSTP?

Comment: SIGTSTP should be handled by the session leader - I think `/bin/login` gets *really* pissed if it doesn't have control of a terminal when it launches - so if it works at all it must become the terminal's session leader and screw your shell `trap`. This is one of the many reasons this is a terrible idea - you don't want a `while` loop - you want *daemon*.

Comment: still, now that I think about it, I guess you might also look into the terminal's job control settings and what signals it passes. try `info stty`.

Comment: That doesn't make a whole lot of sense to me. The trap for SIGINT works (IE if I remove it from my script, I can then ctrl+c out of the login, but if the trap is there I can't). A daemon is probably a better choice but this is how the system is currently set up.

Comment: SIGINT is intended to be handed back to `init` - `login` *allows* it through. I'm really surprised you're able to get `login` up at all. See `man login` - *A recursive login, ... no longer works; ... Indeed, for security reasons, `login` does a `vhangup()` system call to remove any possible listening processes on the tty. This is to avoid password sniffing. If one uses the command `login`, then the **surrounding shell gets killed by `vhangup()`** because it's no longer the true owner of the `tty`. This can be avoided by using `exec login` in a top-level shell or xterm..*

Comment: Another problem with using a daemon is that this script has to output to stdout to tell the user things. Is that kind of thing possible with daemons?

Comment: That depends on the terminal job control settings. I suspect a bigger problem is that you need to study up on how, what, and why we use terminals at all. You could do a lot of this stuff with `screen`, `tmux`, `socat`, `ssh` and pseudoterminals - even `zsh` offers the `zpty` and  `ztcp` builtins - but probably not with `/bin/login`. And all of these provide multiple means of monitoring and scripting - they can be the *daemons* themselves.

Comment: Can you provide any resources for that kind of stuff? This is a very simple script and its only job is to provide some diagnostic messages before launching a game so a daemon seemed overkill. Having the script exit to a login prompt after the game is closed/crashes seemed like it should be trivial. It's very hard (at least for me) to google for these things.

Comment: @CameronBall - if that's it, then why does it need to keep running? Just `exec game`.

Comment: Why does what need to keep running? If you're referring to the terminal, I want to leave that running so that maintenance can be carried out if the game crashes for some reason.

Comment: gotcha - you can usually accomplish same like `(exec process)` - the parent shell blocks until the child returns, I think.